# Windows 10 UWP Smooth Streaming Video set the heuristic profile

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, azure-media-services, smooth-streaming

I got smooth streaming working... that was an adventure but it works nicely with Azure Media Services. However what's not so nice is the blurry video at first because it's fast playing without caching enough to use a higher quality stream.
Using the AMP video player for azure on web you can set the heuristicProfile flag to "High Quality" and voilà it buffers more and uses the higher quality stream.

How does one set the heuristic profile on UWP Video playback with smooth streaming so that it will choose the highest quality resolution that will work with the current connection so that video looks good right from the start of playback?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the Select Track method to select the highest bitrate on startup and then after start unselect that track to allow it to adapt naturally?

See this sample:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-Windows-8-Smooth-883c3b44

Comment: I looked at doing that, but it didn't seem to be the best way. You're forcing buffering on a stream the user may never be able to use. The whole point of the HeuristicProfile is for the player to figure that out automatically and not buffer something it can't use. I.e. someone on a dialup connection doesn't need to buffer 30 seconds of 1080p. It just isn't going to work so why force them to it?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Windows team has exposed access to the HeuristicProfile. As you stated, we do that in our Azure Media Player already today. I'll ask around and try to get back to this thread.